# Javascript count distinct value and sum lists in json array

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, lodash

For example, in the following json array each element has a `name` and a variable list of items in `tracks.items`

```
[
    {
    "name": "whatever",
    "tracks": {
        "items": 
        [
            {
             "item 1" : "some item" 
            },
            ...
        ]
        }
    },
    {...}
    ...
]
```

In javascript, I need to find the number of distinct `name`'s, as well as the sum of the length (size) of all `tracks.items` found in the entire array.
How do I use underscore or lodash to do that?. I've tried `_.countBy()` but that only returns individual counts

**EDIT**
thanks guys
(alternate solution)
`const uniqueNames = new Set(array.map(item => item.name)).size
const totalItems = array.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.tracks.items.length, 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Stucco noted in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49810040/5157454) you can get the number of unique names, by checking the length of the result of [`_.uniqBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#uniqBy) by `name`.

You can get the total amount of track items using [`_.sumBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#sumBy).

```js
var arr = [{"name":"whatever","tracks":{"items":[{"item 1":"some item"},{"item 2":"some item"},{"item 3":"some item"}]}},{"name":"whatever","tracks":{"items":[{"item 4":"some item"},{"item 5":"some item"},{"item 6":"some item"},{"item 7":"some item"}]}},{"name":"whatever2","tracks":{"items":[{"item 8":"some item"},{"item 9":"some item"},{"item 10":"some item"},{"item 11":"some item"}]}}];

var uniqueNamesCount = _.uniqBy(arr, 'name').length;
var totalTracksItemsCount = _.sumBy(arr, 'tracks.items.length');

console.log('uniqueNamesCount', uniqueNamesCount); // 2
console.log('totalTracksItemsCount', totalTracksItemsCount); // 11
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks. can I ask how to count how many times a key occurs in entire json using lodash? i.e. each element has a tracks.items[] list and "url" can appear n number of times in items[]

Comment: Welcome. Please open a new question with relevant data, and expected results.

Answer (score 1):

```
let obj = [{
    "name": "whatever",
    "tracks": {
        "items": 
        [
            {
                "item 1" : "some item" 
            },
            ...
        ]
        }
    },
    {...}
    ...
];

let uniqueNames = _.uniqBy(obj, 'name').length;
let totalItemes = _.reduce(obj, (result, value) => result += value.tracks.items.length, 0);
```

Working example:

```js
var obj = [{
  "name": "whatever",
  "tracks": {
    "items": [{
        "item 1": "some item"
      },
      {
        "item 2": "some item"
      }, {
        "item 3": "some item"
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "name": "whatever",
  "tracks": {
    "items": [{
        "item 4": "some item"
      },
      {
        "item 5": "some item"
      }, {
        "item 6": "some item"
      }, {
        "item 7": "some item"
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "name": "whatever2",
  "tracks": {
    "items": [{
        "item 8": "some item"
      },
      {
        "item 9": "some item"
      }, {
        "item 10": "some item"
      }, {
        "item 11": "some item"
      }
    ]
  }
}]
let names = _.uniqBy(obj, 'name');
let uniqueNames = names.length
let items = _.reduce(obj, (result, value) => result += value.tracks.items.length, 0)
console.log(names);
console.log(uniqueNames)
console.log(items)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```